# Using memcpy correctly

Tags: c

Is it correct to use `memcpy` like that?

```
unsigned char *ptr = mem;
struct st st1[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    memcpy(&st1[i], ptr + sizeof(st) * i, sizeof(st));
}
```

If it is not, how to use it correctly considering this example?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but I fail to see why you would want to copy 3 different things into the same place.

Comment: it just for the example, its supposed to be array of structs

Comment: But you're copying them all to the **exact same** location.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, edited.

Comment: Hmmm; now the question is updated — it is definitively wrong! On the second iteration of the loop, you're copying outside the space allocated to `st1` (because `sizeof(st1)` is the size of the entire array).  A single call to `memcpy()` is sufficient.  You probably need `sizeof(st1[i])` instead of `sizeof(st1)` now.  Changing `sizeof(st1)` to `sizeof(st)` prevents the code compiling under a C compiler; a C++ compiler will accept `sizeof(st)` as meaning `sizeof(struct st)`.

Comment: Anyone incoming to this question: it is a chameleon question — the code keeps changing rather rapidly.

Comment: Humans make mistakes.

Comment: They do (humans do make mistakes), and compilers spot them.  Please make sure your code compiles before asking the question — and make sure you ask the question you mean to ask, not some approximation to it.  It is hard for those trying to help you to do so effectively when you're not sure what you're trying to do and what you're trying to ask.

Comment: `memcpy( st1, ptr, sizeof(st1) )` will copy the whole thing with a single call.

Comment: I'm serializing each struct separately

Comment: @Neet33: that is no serialization. `memcopy` might very well copy the data in parallel or jumping randomly. There is absolutely no use in the loop.

Comment: Well at least now we know what the question is about. No, that is not the recommended way to serialize a `struct`, especially if serialization and deserialization will occur on different machines.  Serializing with `memcpy` creates problems with endian-ness, alignment, and padding.

Answer (score 0):

If `mem` actually points to bytes which form a valid representation for a `struct st` then this code is correct, apart from `sizeof(st)` which should be `sizeof(struct st)` or `sizeof st1[i]`.  However, since the three blocks are contiguous you could have done it all in one copy:

```
memcpy(&st1, ptr, sizeof st1);
```

If `mem` does not point to such bytes then this whole approach will not work.